# Set a column value into an output parameter of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure to retrieve the average of a column and back it to another stored procedure. Now I don't know how to set the value of output to the column value.

Thank you in advance :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AverageGrade
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @course_grade INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        PersonID, AVG(Grade) AS averagegrade 
    FROM
        Enrollment 
    GROUP BY
        PersonID;

    SELECT @course_grade = averagegrade;
END
GO
```

Comment: Need a little more information. Is it an actual table or a table variable? Can you post what you tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Read what you wrote. "I don't know how to **set** the value ...".

Notice the key word - set. Now go look up the syntax for [tsql set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) since that is how you **should** assign a value to a scalar variable.

To assign the value of your query to your variable, you use the form:

```
set @blah = (select ...);
```

Example F in the documentation provides a complete example. Go read it and learn it.